# How can I see the Django development server in VMWare?

Tags: django, vmware

I am trying to connect to a Django development server, running in OS X localhost:8000, from VMWare running Windows.

I've tried various combinations of settings, but none of them seem to work:

- Running the Django server on localhost:8000, and in Windows, connecting to the IP address assigned to the Mac by VMWare, i.e. 192.168.XX.XX:8000
- Running the Django server on port 80
- Running the Django server on the Mac's IP assigned by VMWare, e.g. python manage.py runserver 192.168.XX.XX:8000

None of these seem to work. I have an Apache server also running locally, and am able to connect to that, so it's not an issue with the network.  Is there any way to connect to localhost:8000 from within VMWare?

### **Update**: To get this to work, I used the following settings:

- In VMWare, set the network of the VM to "Connect directly to the physical network (Bridged)", rather than "Share this Mac's network connection (NAT)"
- Find the IP address of the Mac itself on the network the Mac itself is on (not the private network VMWare sets up), e.g. 192.168.1.2.  This can be found in ifconfig, or in System Preferences > Network
- Start the Django development server on that IP address: sudo python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.2:80
- In VMWare, connect to the Django site at 192.168.1.2

Thanks to randrumree for the answer below -- this is essentially the same solution.

Comment: What is the IP address of the Mac, and what is the IP address of the VM?  It may be important depending on how the VM is set up.

Comment: Your steps worked for me. I recommend adding them as an answer to this question and making it complete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- In VMWare, set the network of the VM to "Connect directly to the
  physical network (Bridged)", rather than "Share this Mac's network
  connection (NAT)"
- Find the IP address of the Mac itself on the
  network the Mac itself is on (not the private network VMWare sets
  up).  This can be found using `ifconfig`, or in System
  Preferences > Network.  Let's say it's `192.168.1.2`.
- Start the Django development server on that IP
  address: `python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.2:8000`
- In VMWare, connect to the Django site at `http://192.168.1.2:8000`

Comment: The problem with this approach, is that I can no longer ssh into the VM.

Comment: You can SSH by using `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` on your VM. Then you can ssh from host using `ssh username@vm_ip_same_as_host_ip`.  See [Ubuntu serverguide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html) for config options.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either.  I tried accessing it as localhost:8000. 0.0.0.0:8000, 127.0.0.1:8000 and various other combinations from Windows, still not responding.

Comment: For Windows, localhost (and 127.0.0.1) is Windows. Django is under 192.168.whatever (Mac's IP visible from Windows).

Answer (score 3):

I got it working one time with a Django Development Server running inside a Ubuntu 11.04 VM.

I was able to access the development server outside that VM on Windows 7 by setting the ip in python manage.py runserver (local ip of the OS X machine here, not localhost):8000 to the same ip as the computer it was running on, in your case, the OS X.

My VM was set up to have its own IP address different from that of the host.

Since it's just the other way around, I would suspect your set-up should work too.

Perhaps you should check whether the VM can ping the OS X computer and vice versa or if their IP's are unique.